# Create List of Control Groups in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, controls

I'm building an control interface for a system that consists of 1-4 modules.  In my interface, each module has its own control set, grouped in a groupbox.  I only want to show the control groups for the modules that are actually connected and hide the rest.

This is easy to do with the visble property.

I also want all of the groups to be stacked vertically in the UI such that when one is hidden, the rest below it shift up into its place as if you deleted a row in a table.  It needs to be able to come back just as easily.

How can I do this or something similar in VB.Net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FlowLayoutPanel control does this automatically.  Just put the group boxes inside of it.